# Invoking AWS Lambda via Unsigned POST to REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to have a form on my Jekyll website that visitors can fill out, and the `form` `action` should `POST` to an AWS Lambda function. No JavaScript is allowed on the website, so the `POST` must not require signing.

I want the simplest possible setup, and do not need high security. If there is a way to avoid using AWS API Gateway to create an HTTP API, and somehow have the Lambda function directly receive the `POST` from the user's web browser, that would be perfect. If API Gateway is required, then the simplest solution would be best.

I want to use command line commands exclusively (not a web browser) to work with the AWS API. This allows for a scripted solution.

I've spent some time on the problem, and here is what I've got. I've marked questions in the `deploy` script with `TODO`. There is some extra code in that script which might not be needed. Problem is, I'm unsure what to delete because I just can't figure out how to provide the `POST` to the lambda.

The scripts use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) so the bash scripts can parse JSON and YAML, respectively.

**_config.yml**

```yaml
aws:
  cloudfront:
    distributionId: "" # Provide value if CloudFront is used on this site
  lambda:
    addSubscriber:
      custom: # TODO change these values to suit your website
        iamRoleName: lambda-ex
        name: addSubscriberAwsLambdaSample
        handler: addSubscriberAwsLambda.lambda_handler
        runtime: python3.8
      computed: # These values are computed by the _bin/awsLambda setup and deploy scripts
        arn: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:031372724784:function:addSubscriberAwsLambdaSample:3
        iamRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::031372724784:role/lambda-ex
```

**utils** source bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

function readYaml {
  # $1 - path
  yq r _config.yml "$1"
}

function writeYaml {
  # $1 - path
  # $2 - value
  yq w -i _config.yml "$1" "$2"
}


# AWS Lambda values
export LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_ARN="$(  readYaml aws.lambda.addSubscriber.computed.iamRoleArn )"
export LAMBDA_NAME="$(          readYaml aws.lambda.addSubscriber.custom.name         )"
export LAMBDA_RUNTIME="$(       readYaml aws.lambda.addSubscriber.custom.runtime      )"
export LAMBDA_HANDLER="$(       readYaml aws.lambda.addSubscriber.custom.handler      )"
export LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_NAME="$( readYaml aws.lambda.addSubscriber.custom.iamRoleName  )"

export PACKAGE_DIR="${GIT_ROOT}/_package"
export LAMBDA_ZIP="${PACKAGE_DIR}/function.zip"

# Misc values
export TITLE="$( readYaml title )"
export URL="$( readYaml url )"
export DOMAIN="$( echo "$URL" | sed -n -e 's,^https\?://,,p' )"
```

**setup** bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Inspired by https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-awscli.html

SOURCE_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

GIT_ROOT="$( git rev-parse --show-toplevel )"
cd "${GIT_ROOT}"
source _bin/utils

# Define the execution role that gives an AWS Lambda function permission to access AWS resources.
read -r -d '' ROLE_POLICY_JSON <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF

# If a role named $LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_NAME is already defined then use it
ROLE_RESULT="$( aws iam get-role --role-name "$LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_NAME" 2> /dev/null )"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  ROLE_RESULT="$( aws iam create-role \
    --role-name "$LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_NAME" \
    --assume-role-policy-document "$ROLE_POLICY_JSON"
  )"
fi
LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_ARN="$( jq -r .Role.Arn <<< "$ROLE_RESULT" )"
writeYaml aws.lambda.addSubscriber.computed.iamRoleArn "$LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_ARN"
```

**deploy** bash script

```
# Call this script after the setup script has created the IAM role
# that gives the addSubscriber AWS Lambda function permission to access AWS resources
#
# 1) This script builds the AWS Lambda package and deploys it, with permissions.
#    Any previous version of the AWS Lambda is deleted.
#
# 2) The newly (re)created AWS Lambda ARN is stored in _config.yml
#
# 3) An AWS Gateway HTTP API is created so static web pages can POST subscriber information to the AWS Lambda function.
#    Because the web page is not allowed to have JavaScript, the POST is unsigned.
#    *** The API must allow for an unsigned POST!!! ***

# Set cwd to the git project root
GIT_ROOT="$( git rev-parse --show-toplevel )"
cd "${GIT_ROOT}"

# Load configuration environment variables from _bin/utils:
# DOMAIN, LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_ARN, LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_NAME, LAMBDA_HANDLER, LAMBDA_NAME, LAMBDA_RUNTIME, LAMBDA_ZIP, PACKAGE_DIR, and URL
source _bin/utils

# Directory that this script resides in
SOURCE_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

echo "Building the AWS Lambda and packaging it into a zip file"
"$SOURCE_DIR/package" "$PACKAGE_DIR" > /dev/null

# Check to see if the Lambda function already exists.
LAMBDA="$( aws lambda list-functions | jq ".Functions[] | select(.FunctionName | contains(\"$LAMBDA_NAME\"))" )"

if [ -z "$LAMBDA" ]; then
  echo "The AWS Lambda function '$LAMBDA_NAME' does not exist yet, so create it"
  LAMBDA_METADATA="$( aws lambda create-function \
    --description "Add subscriber to the MailChimp list with ID '$MC_LIST_ID_MSLINN' for the '$DOMAIN' website" \
    --environment "{
      \"Variables\": {
        \"MC_API_KEY_MSLINN\": \"$MC_API_KEY_MSLINN\",
        \"MC_LIST_ID_MSLINN\": \"$MC_LIST_ID_MSLINN\",
        \"MC_USER_NAME_MSLINN\": \"$MC_USER_NAME_MSLINN\"
      }
    }" \
    --function-name "$LAMBDA_NAME" \
    --handler "$LAMBDA_HANDLER" \
    --role "arn:aws:iam::${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/$LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_NAME" \
    --runtime "$LAMBDA_RUNTIME" \
    --zip-file "fileb://$LAMBDA_ZIP" \
    | jq -S .
  )"
  LAMBDA_ARN="$( jq -r .Configuration.FunctionArn <<< "$LAMBDA_METADATA" )"
else
  echo "The AWS Lambda function '$LAMBDA_NAME' already exists, so update it"
  LAMBDA_METADATA="$( aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name "$LAMBDA_NAME" \
    --publish \
    --zip-file "fileb://$LAMBDA_ZIP" \
    | jq -S .
  )"
  LAMBDA_ARN="$( jq -r .FunctionArn <<< "$LAMBDA_METADATA" )"
fi
echo "AWS Lambda ARN is $LAMBDA_ARN"
writeYaml aws.lambda.addSubscriber.computed.arn "$LAMBDA_ARN"

echo "Attach the AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole managed policy to $LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_NAME."
aws iam attach-role-policy \
  --role-name $LAMBDA_IAM_ROLE_NAME \
  --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole


#### Integrate with API Gateway for REST
#### Some or all of the following code is probably not required

GATEWAY_NAME="addSubscriberTo_$MC_LIST_ID_MSLINN"

API_GATEWAYS="$( aws apigateway get-rest-apis )"
if [ "$( jq ".items[] | select(.name | contains(\"$GATEWAY_NAME\"))" <<< "$API_GATEWAYS" )" ]; then
  echo "API gateway '$GATEWAY_NAME' already exists."
else
  echo "Creating API gateway '$GATEWAY_NAME'."

  API_JSON="$( aws apigateway create-rest-api \
    --name "$GATEWAY_NAME" \
    --description "API for adding a subscriber to the Mailchimp list with ID '$MC_LIST_ID_MSLINN' for the '$DOMAIN' website"
  )"
  REST_API_ID="$( jq -r .id <<< "$API_JSON" )"

  API_RESOURCES="$( aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id $REST_API_ID )"
  ROOT_RESOURCE_ID="$( jq -r .items[0].id <<< "$API_RESOURCES" )"

  NEW_RESOURCE="$( aws apigateway create-resource \
    --rest-api-id "$REST_API_ID" \
    --parent-id "$RESOURCE_ID" \
    --path-part "{proxy+}"
  )"
  NEW_RESOURCE_ID=$( jq -r .id <<< $NEW_RESOURCE )

if false; then
  # Is this step useful for any reason?
  aws apigateway put-method \
    --authorization-type "NONE" \
    --http-method ANY \
    --resource-id "$NEW_RESOURCE_ID" \
    --rest-api-id "$REST_API_ID"
fi

# The following came from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-using-cli
#   Instead of supplying an IAM role for --credentials, call the add-permission command to add resource-based permissions.
#   I need an example of this.
# Alternatively, how to obtain IAM_ROLE_ID? Again, I need an example.
  aws apigateway put-integration \
    --credentials "arn:aws:iam::${IAM_ROLE_ID}:role/apigAwsProxyRole" \
    --http-method ANY \
    --integration-http-method POST \
    --rest-api-id "$REST_API_ID" \
    --resource-id "$NEW_RESOURCE_ID" \
    --type AWS_PROXY \
    --uri arn:aws:apigateway:`aws configure get region`:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/$LAMBDA_ARN

  if [ "$LAMBDA_TEST"]; then
    # Deploy the API to a test stage
    aws apigateway create-deployment \
      --rest-api-id "$REST_API_ID" \
      --stage-name test
  else
    # Deploy the API live
    aws apigateway create-deployment \
      --rest-api-id "$REST_API_ID" \
      --stage-name TODO_WhatNameGoesHere
  fi
fi

echo "Check out the defined lambdas at https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/functions"
```

Comment: You can’t access lambda directly from a browser without JavaScript. You need api gateway. Just don’t put any security on it. It’s easy.

Comment: I disagree with "easy", but if you want a lambda function to handle the submission of an anonymous POST request from a vanilla HTML form, api gateway is the right tool to use.

Comment: @bryan60, I'd love to know what to do for the easy solution. If you can provide a simple answer, please do so. I've probably written most of the API Gateway code in the lower half of the `deploy` script, although it certainly needs corrections.

Comment: Just use the aws sam cli. It takes 15 minutes to set up a script To deploy a gateway and lambda

Comment: @bryan60 Yes, yes, I know. Please be specific. I've worked hard to try to get a proper answer.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason can you suggest API Gateway calls using AWS CLIs to allow unsigned POSTs to be rougted to the lambda function by API Gateway? ... even broad strokes?

Answer (score 0):

Bash scripting infrastructure is bad. You might get it right eventually, but there are tools that make the process infinitely easier.

I prefer Terraform, and here's how an API Gateway + lambda would look like:

```
provider "aws" {
}

# lambda

resource "random_id" "id" {
  byte_length = 8
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "/tmp/lambda.zip"
  source {
    content  = <<EOF
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
// write the lambda code here
    }
};
EOF
    filename = "main.js"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = "${random_id.id.hex}-function"

  filename         = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256

  handler = "main.handler"
  runtime = "nodejs12.x"
  role    = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_exec_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "loggroup" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.lambda.function_name}"
  retention_in_days = 14
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "lambda_exec_role" {
  role   = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_exec_role_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_exec" {
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

# api gw

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "api" {
  name          = "api-${random_id.id.hex}"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
  target        = aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

output "domain" {
  value = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.api_endpoint
}
```

See that the last 2 resources are the API Gateway, all the previous ones are for the Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. However, I am in fact looking for a bash solution. Seems that the last 2 resources contain the answer. If the API GateWay code you show was described by a a series of aws cli invocations then I could test by using CURL to POST to the endpoint.